# Transform and transpose byte[] of 32bit image data in 24bit array image data

Tags: c#, performance, image, pointers

I would like to know if someone can think about a better solution for doing this stuff.

I have an array of raw bitmap data in 32bit format (RGBA). I need to transform **and** transpose this array into a 24bit format by eliminating the alpha component.

Additionally I need to transform the data by aligning the red component in the first part of the result array, the green in after the first 1/3 and the blue after the 2/3  because I'm doing a RLE compression after.

By doing this alignment, I have a better compression because there is more chance to have red, green and blue component alignment between pixels.

I'm using unsafe and fixed pointer to do that. I'm getting something like 11ms to process for a 8.3M array length. It seems to be low but I'm doing a realtime screengrabbing and every ms is counting.

(I bypass unsafe and fixed `byte*` stuff):

```
byte* actualpointeur = actual == (IntPtr)pd1 ? pd1 : pd2; // it s the pointer on my source 32bit array
// pd24b is a pointeur to my reception array at the right size...
byte* redindexp = pd24b;
byte* greenindexp = pd24b+(datain24format.Length / 3);
byte* blueindexp = pd24b+((datain24format.Length / 3) * 2);
for (int i = 0; i < datalenght; i += 4, actualpointeur+=4, redindexp++, greenindexp++, blueindexp++)
{
    *redindexp= *(actualpointeur);
    *greenindexp = *(actualpointeur+1);
    *blueindexp = *(actualpointeur+2);
}
```